# SQL function always return wrong value

Tags: sql, constraints, sql-server-2016

I'm making database to manage conferences and i'm trying to add constraint that prevents two date ranges from overlapping. My function to check that looks like this:

```
create function DateOverlapping 
(
    @ConferenceID int,
    @BeginDate date,
    @EndDate date
)
returns bit

as begin

declare @valid bit = 1;


if exists (select * 
            from PaymentsThreshold 
            where ConferenceID = @ConferenceID 
            and @BeginDate < ToDate and @EndDate > FromDate)
begin
    set @valid = 0; 
end 

 return @valid;
 end
```

However those function always returns 0, even when i'm trying to add record to an empty table.
Can anyone help me with this problem?

@hatchet i'm adding check constrait to PaymentsThreshold table:

```
alter table dbo.PaymentsThreshold with nocheck add constraint CK_pt_dates_chronology 
check (dbo.DateOverlapping(ConferenceID, FromDate, ToDate) = 1);
```

and then i'm trying to insert some data (to an ampty table):

```
insert into PaymentsThreshold values(1, '2017-03-11', '2017-05-11', 0.2)
```

and that results with an error

Comment: Is it possible this function is called after the row is already added? That would explain always getting 0. How exactly is this function getting called?

Comment: Note: there is no `@` in SQL. Maybe are using some SQL-like product? -->> please add your DBMS to the tags.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding why you always get 0. Constraint checks are done **after** the row has been added. You only check for overlap against the row you just added, that would guarantee you will always get 0 because a row always overlaps itself. You need to exclude the newly added row from the check. You want `ConferenceId <> @ConferenceId`. That way, you check for overlap with any row **except** the one you just added.

```
if exists (select * 
            from PaymentsThreshold 
            where ConferenceID <> @ConferenceID 
            and @BeginDate < ToDate and @EndDate > FromDate)
begin
    set @valid = 0; 
end
```

Comment: I'm curious to know why the downvote, a month after the question was asked, and this answer accepted.